# how to kill all processed from "lsof -i"

Tags: linux, terminal, kill-process

How do I kill all processes returned from the following?

```
lsof -i
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
lsof -i | awk '{print $2}' | kill
```

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: The pipeline would only work if `kill` read from its stdin. It doesn't take a list of processes to kill on stdin; it gets them from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kill` takes PID's as its arguments whereas when you pipe it, it goes to the stdin of `kill`.

Pass them as arguments:

```
kill $(lsof -i | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: You probably want to add a `tail -n+2` in there, to filter out the header.

Comment: or just use `lsof -ti` and drop the awk completely